# Calling specific tests on Appium

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, appium

Would it be possible in Appium to make a script that calls/references specific tests (e.g test1, test4, test27) to run? So instead of moving files over into the test folder I could just call them using the script is the rough idea I have but I have no idea if it's possible and I haven't been able to find anything similar online.

Comment: It all depends which framework you are using. If you are using testng you can run any specific test

Comment: @Gaurav I'm using just Appium w/ mocha & webdriverio right now but I think TestNG doesn't support JS right? Is there a another framework that is capable of this that you would recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create group test cases And Create testng.xml file and just invoke testng file and run.

```
code mport org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class GroupTestExample {
String message = ".com";
MessageUtil messageUtil = new MessageUtil(message);

@Test(groups = { "functest", "RunOnlySelectedTestCases" })

public void test1() {
  System.out.println("Inside testPrintMessage()");
  message = ".com";
  Assert.assertEquals(message, messageUtil.printMessage());
}

@Test(groups = { "RunOnlySelectedTestCases" })

public void test4() {
  System.out.println("Inside testSalutationMessage()");
  message = "tutorialspoint" + ".com";
  Assert.assertEquals(message, messageUtil.salutationMessage());
 }

@Test(groups = { "RunOnlySelectedTestCases" })

 public void test27() {
  System.out.println("Inside testExitMessage()");
  message = "www." + "tutorialspoint"+".com";
  Assert.assertEquals(message, messageUtil.exitMessage());
  }  
   }  


?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name = "Suite1">
<test name = "test1">
  <groups>
     <run>
        <include name = "RunOnlySelectedTestCases" />
     </run>
    </groups>
  </test>
 </suite>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! I'm new to this whole testing thing so I just have a couple questions if that's alright. I'm currently using JS for all my tests and I think TestNg only supports Java right? Is there another framework capable of this that supports javascript also?

Comment: https://mochajs.org/

Try with mochas frame work , it is easy to use and implements

Comment: Thanks a bunch Mocha works great! I ended up installing mocha awesome too